# Change backcolor of ListView item on specific condition

Tags: c#, listview, backcolor

I have a listview that consists of three columns, one of those is a 'status' column. I want the backcolor of the cell in this column to color either green of red based on the value that's in there, but so far I haven't been able to find the right solution.

I've found a lot information on applying a backcolor to a full row, but nothing yet on doing so for a cell with a specific value. Nothing that seems to work, at least.

```
if (emp.SubItems[2].ToString() == "AANWEZIG")
                {
                    emp.BackColor = Color.Green;
                }
```

Comment: try changing it when its drawn

Comment: That's what it already does; it's inside a method, that is invoked upon launch. Or is that not what you're referring to?

Comment: No, theres a drawitem method, its normal to change colours etc there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, when you're creating your `ListViewItem` instances, you need to set [`ListViewItem.UseItemStyleForSubItems`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.useitemstyleforsubitems) to `false`. This way, the `ListViewItem`'s `Font`, `ForeColor`, and `BackColor` won't be used for all the subitems.

Second, your `if` statement needs to check the `ListViewSubItem.Text` property, rather than the result of `ToString`. `ToString` doesn't just return the text.

Finally, set `ListViewSubItem.BackColor` based on the text.

```csharp
private void LoadListView()
{
   // Build up the ListViewItem that you're calling emp in your original question...
   emp.UseItemStyleForSubItems = false;
   if (emp.SubItems[2].Text == "AANWEZIG")
   {
      emp.SubItems[2].BackColor = Color.Green;
   }
}
```